# $\DeclareMathOperator\sym{sym}$Does $L(s, \sym^2 f \times \sym^2 g)$ have a pole at $s=1$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\sym{sym}$I encountered a question on the poles of $\GL_3\times \GL_3$ $L$-function, which needs the knowledge of the experts here.

Let $f$ be an $\SL_2$ newform of level $P$ (such as a primitive holomorphic form) and $g$ a newform with trivial level. Does any expert here know whether or not the $L$-function $L(s, \sym^2 f \times  \sym^2 g)$ has a pole at $s=1$? If not, how about the upper-bound of the $L$-value at $s=1$? I guess $L(1, \sym^2 f \times  \sym^2 g)\ll P^\varepsilon$, but I don't know any ideas of the proof.

If any experts here know something about this question, please give a guide sharing some of your valuable comments or give some references.

Comment: Hello. Note that some ladies here may possibly not appreciate to be named by "guys".

Comment: I deleted the opening phrase "guys" as inappropriate. MathOverflow is not a casual chat site, but a scientific forum.

Comment: @ F.C. @GH from MO   Really sorry if any offense. I will improve the post editing.

Comment: But I really wanna know if somewhere said about $L(1, \text{sym}^2 f  \times \text{sym}^2 g)$? If $f\neq g$, the property of $L(1, \text{sym}^2 f  \times \text{sym}^2 g)$ has ever been studied before?

Comment: Yes, there is no pole at $s = 1$. Since $f$ has level $1$ and $g$ has level $P$ (assuming that $g$ has trivial nebentypus), their symmetric square lifts are cuspidal; they are also not dual to each other since $\mathrm{sym}^2 f$ has level $1$ whereas $\mathrm{sym}^2 g$ has level $P$. The Rankin-Selberg convolution of two cuspidal automorphic forms can only have a pole at $s = 1$ if they are dual to each other.

Comment: There should be a bound of the form $L(1,\mathrm{sym}^2 f \otimes \mathrm{sym}^2 g) \ll_{\varepsilon} P^{\varepsilon}$ by an application of the main result of Xiannan Li's Ph.D. thesis.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Many thanks to your comments and reference!

Comment: @PeterHumphries Why not make this an answer, so the question does not go 'unanswered'?